# Confusion about 大したこと(で)(は)ない

Tags: particles, expressions

There are three variations on this phrase that I can find in Google, and I'm not sure whether all three are really used, or how frequently. But I am confused about the differences between them.

> 大{たい}したこと**では**ない

I believe this means "(It's) not a big deal." Ok, I understand.

> 大{たい}したこと**は**ない

Isn't this different from the first sentence? It seems to mean "There aren't any particularly big problems."

> 大{たい}したことない

This one could go either way.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the first two variations is correct. The sound quite formal, maybe something like:

1. "This is nothing important, really"
2. "There is nothing important, really"

Last variation is more colloquial, maybe something like:

3. "No big deal"

Comment: But I'm wondering about the last variation, is it like が (or は) is omitted before ない, meaning 大した is the subject of ない? Or could it be that では is omitted (although I don't think this is allowed), meaning 大した is the predicate?

Comment: It is like が or は is omitted before ない. "ない" is the short, informal version of "ありません". On the other hand, the informal version of "ではありません"  / "ではない" would be "じゃない" (or even a more rough sounding "じゃねえ"). "大したことじゃねえんだから気にすんなよ！"